# Fragments inside tabs

Tags: java, android, layout, tabs, fragment

I'm creating menu which has two tabs. Each tab has three fragments which show the content. I though this would be straightforward but after experimenting and Googling it looks like I were wrong.

I managed to create fragments to the first tab. However, when I change to other tab and back, I get the following error message and app crashes:

```
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at com.machinedata.ui.feedback.UsersFragment.onCreateView(UsersFragment.java:16)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #8: Duplicate id 0x7f0b0013, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.machinedata.ui.UserListFragment
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4252)
07-11 16:49:57.829: E/AndroidRuntime(20009):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
```

Now my tabs are fragments themselves, which are placed dynamically to the screen. These fragments then inflate xml-files which have fragments placed in them statically. After some googling I found out that placing fragments inside fragments is a bit tricky.

getChildFragmentManager works in API level 17, but I'd like to keep API level in 14. Is there anyway to create this kind of menu structure? Do I need to create separate Activities for tabs?

Here is my activity which displays the tabs:

```
    public class FeedbackActivity extends Activity implements UserListFragment.OnItemClickedListener
{

    private ToplistsFragment toplist;
    private UsersFragment users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        setContentView(R.layout.feedback_screen);

        //create tabs for dashboard and graphs
        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.feedbackUsers);
        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.feedbackToplist);
        toplist = new ToplistsFragment();
        users = new UsersFragment();
        tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(toplist));
        tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(users));
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("log","ID: " + item.getItemId() + " " + item.getTitle());
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
           {        
              case android.R.id.home: 
                  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ModeSelectActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);        
                 return true;    


              default:            
                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);    
           }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUserItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id, UserData user) 
    { 
        //wite your activity code here  

        Log.v("log", "name: " + user.getName());     
    }


    //tablistener
    class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener 
    {
        public Fragment fragment;

        public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) 
        {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
        {
            ft.replace(R.id.feedback_fragcontainer, fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) 
        {
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }

    }
}
```

Its xml-file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/feedback_fragcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And tab-fragment's xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/feedbackuserListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.machinedata.ui.UserListFragment" >

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/feedbackSessionListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.machinedata.ui.feedback.SessionListFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/feedbackDetailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.machinedata.ui.feedback.DetailsFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>




</LinearLayout>
```

To be honest, I'm not sure what the error message means with duplicate id, or what causes it. Basically I'm looking a solution to either create menu structure I described or way to fix my current implementation.

Comment: That layout does not appear to be what `onCreateView()` of `UsersFragment` is inflating. The stack trace complains of problems inflating a `<fragment>` element, and your layout posted here does not contain this. Are you sure that `onCreateView()` is inflating the right layout?

Comment: instead of "normal" fragment use the one from support library http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: Forgot to add the tab's xml-file. Activity should inflate feedback_screen.xml and UsersFragment (tab) should inflate feedbackusers_tab.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested fragment functionality (implemented on API level 17) are provided in support package too. Extend your fragment from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`. And replace your parent activity to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.